# Does all processes in which entropy of universe increase occurs?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If water kept at room temperature become ice by its own then total entropy of universe increases theoretically . Since heat change between system and surrounding is same and system is at lower temperature than surrounding. But we know that the process is not spontaneous. Why?

Comment: The premise is incorrect. At room temperature, the entropy increase of the surroundings from endothermic freezing is less than the entropy decrease of the water from solidification. Thus, the process is not spontaneous, consistent with our observations.

Comment: Can you explain how the entropy increase of surrounding is less than the entropy decrease of water.

Comment: Because the entropy increase to the surroundings is around $L/293\,\mathrm{K}$ (where $L$ is the enthalpy of fusion), whereas the entropy decrease to the water is the larger $L/273\,\mathrm{K}$.